# PubSub increase/decrease CloudSQL memory when a new GAE instance is created or removed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-pubsub

How can I create a pub/sub topic to run the below command when a new GAE instance is deployed?

`gcloud sql instances patch <instance_name> --cpu=2 --memory=8GB`

And the below command when the load balancer remove this instance?

`gcloud sql instances patch <instance_name> --cpu=1 --memory=6GB`

Comment: When you reffer to "create a pub/sub topic", are you actually referring to "send a message to a Pub/sub topic"? Also, by changing the CPU or memory, you will face a few minutes of downtime. Are you okey with that?

Comment: @NahuelVarelaBlanco I just wanna a way to increase/decrease cpu and memory when reach x instances of GAE. I think that pub/sub topic it's a way to do this, what do you think? About the downtime, even with Cloud SQL replication/high availability enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing would be to get the amount of instances of a given service, you can achieve it with `apps.services.versions.instances.list` [method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions.instances/list). After that, you should use the Cloud SQL API using [curl](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance#create-2ndgen-curl) to manage the instances.

The second part will be to automate this, for this I can think of using [Cloud Scheluder](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) every X amount of time to trigger either:

- Pub/Sub to publish to a Topic, which is going to trigger a Cloud
  Function to run the code.
- Target the App engine HTTP handler which is going to run the code

Apart from this, take into account that if you change the Cloud SQL instance, you would be experiencing downtime for a few minutes. You could in turn create a failover, change it and then perform the fail over. Keep in mind that this will generate extra cost for the period of time the failover is up and also, you will change the zone of the Cloud instance.

**Edit [High Availability](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability):**

High Availability creates a second instance for data redundancy. It is meant for the moment the primary instance becomes unhealthy by switching to a newer instance with the same data.

As explained in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#failover-process):

> 1. The primary instance fails.
> 2. Each second, the primary instance writes to system database as a
>      heartbeat signal. If multiple heartbeats aren't detected (and the
>      failover replica is healthy), failover is initiated. This occurs if
>      the primary instance is unresponsive for approximately 60 seconds or
>      the primary zone experiences an outage.
> 3. Cloud SQL waits for the failover replica to catch up to the primary
>      instance's state.
> 4. The amount of time this step takes is affected by replication lag.
> 5. The failover replica is promoted to the primary instance role.
> 6. The failover replica now serves data from the secondary zone, and the
>      primary instance name and IP address move to the old failover replica.
>      The client application reconnects to the new primary instance without
>      needing to change its connection string because the primary instance
>      IP address has moved automatically. To see what zone your instance is
>      serving data from, go to its Overview page in the GCP Console.
> 7. A failover replica is recreated.
> 8. The new failover replica retains the incoming failover replica IP
>      address and is automatically recreated in a healthy zone.
> 9. Read replicas are recreated.
>
> New read replicas retain the incoming read replica IP address and are
>   automatically recreated in a healthy zone.

Comment: Just to be sure: **With high availability enabled**, when I change the settings of the SQL instance and it restarts, there will be a downtime?

Comment: If you change the settings on the Master and restart, then yes. If you change the settings on the failover and then proceed to perform the failover, then the downtime will be minimized.